# How to get div tag by using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to get some data from a website. It looks like

```
<div id="1" class="tms"> 
    <div class="point">
     TINAZTEPE
    </div> 
    <div class="days"> 
     <div class="day">
      Hafta İçi
     </div> 
     <div>
      "06:45" 
      <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
     </div> 
     <div>
      "07:00" 
      <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
     </div> 
     <div>
      "07:15" 
      <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
     </div> 
     <div>
      "07:25" 
      <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
     </div> 
     <div>
      "07:30" 
      <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
     </div> 
     <div>
      "07:45" 
      <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
     </div>
```

I just need to get the time values in div tags. That is my Java code

```
 ArrayList<String> info=new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://nevakit.com/otobus/izmir/412").get();
        Elements broadcasts = document.select("div[id=1]");

        for (Element element : broadcasts) {

            info.add(element.getElementsByTag("div").text());

        }

        String total=null;
        for(String temp:info)
        {
            total+=temp;
        }

        txtView.setText(total);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It doesn't give any error but on logcat

> "D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default"

I saw that maybe that can help you to solve the issue. Thank you in advance, any response will be appreciated.

Comment: make sure you add INTERNET permission in manifest

Comment: Actually, it is added but textView doesn't show anything.

Comment: I have just seen the exception

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AsynTask to perform this operation use below code

```
 class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        ArrayList<String> info=new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try
            {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://nevakit.com/otobus/izmir/412").get();
                Elements broadcasts = document.select("div[id=1]");

                for (Element element : broadcasts) {

                    info.add(element.getElementsByTag("div").text());

                }


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            String total=null;
             for(String temp:info)
                {
                    total+=temp;
                }
            txtView.setText(total);
        }
    }
```

And call it from OnCrate like below

```
new PerformTask().execute();
```

Comment: Yes, finally it's working thank you so much =). By the way, is there any reason why we cannot use directly in onCreate method ?

Comment: @furkandogu beacuse you can't perform such type of operation directly on main thread that's why for more reffer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: @furkandogu if answer helped you then don't forgot to accept it as right